# Cannot access elements of json object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This is more of a json question but since it is within wordpress and is being processed by `admin-ajax.php` I thought it suits this forum best. I have created a standard ajax form procedure as shown below.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="stock-search-form" />               
     <input class="stock-search-element" type="search" name="stock-search-name" id="stock-search-id"/>
     <input class="hide-me" type="hidden" name="action" value="process_stock" />
     <button class="stock-button" name="stock-button-name" id="stock-button-id" type="send">Search</button>                
</form>
<div class="stock-table-outer"></div>
```

PHP:

```
function process_stock() {
    $the_php_result = array("foo1" => "String_1", 
                            "foo2" => "String_2", 
                            "foo3" => "String_3", 
                            "foo4" => "String_4", 
                            "foo5" => "String_5", 
                            "foo6" => "String_6", 
                            "foo7" => "String_7", 
                            "foo8" => "String_8", 
                            "foo9" => "String_9", 
                            "foo10" => "String_10", 
                            "foo11" => "String_11", 
                            "foo12" => "String_12",
                            "foo13" => "String_13",
                            );
    echo json_encode($the_php_result);
}
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery('#stock-search-form').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

var StockSymbolUI = jQuery(this).serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: StockSymbolUI,
    success:function(data){
        jQuery(".stock-table-outer").show();
        jQuery(".stock-table-outer").html(data);
    }
});

return false;
}
```

The result I get returned at the front end is this:

```
{"foo1":"String_1","foo2":"String_2","foo3":"String_3",
"foo4":"String_4","foo5":"String_5","foo6":"String_6",
"foo7":"String_7","foo8":"String_8","foo9":"String_9",
"foo10":"String_10","foo11":"String_11","foo12":"String_12",
"foo13":"String_13"}
```

This at first glance looks like a json object but I dont believe it is.

What I want to do is access the elements of the object, but if I give `data[0]` instead of `data` in the success of the jquery code, all I get is `{`, i.e. the first character of the string. I have tried using `JSON.parse(data)` or `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` as suggested elsewhere but then I get nothing returned.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been stuck with this for a whole day...

Harry

Comment: What's outputted to the console if you use `console.log( data )` in your `succes` callback function? And what's outputted to the console if you do the same but use `dataType: 'json'` as an additional parameter to `jQuery.ajax()`?

Comment: I think this is going to the right direction.. The `console.log(data)` gave the same as the result in the original question. The `console.log(data)` with `dataType: 'json'` gave `Object {foo1: "String_1", ..., foo13: "String_13"}` followed by `__proto__:Object`. So this did turn my result into a real object? The thing is that now the `jQuery(".stock-table-outer").html(data);` returns nothing. If I do `JSON.parse(data)` or `jQuery.grep( jQuery.parseJSON(data))` I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` because of `[object Object]`x

Comment: OK... Engelen Thanks!!! That was it.. If I call `jQuery(".stock-table-outer").html(data.foo1);` I get what I want!!!! Thanks man.

Comment: If you want, please post the answer so that I can upvote it and mark it as the solution. Otherwise I will close the thread with a follow-up answer tto my question.. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to be of help! I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result that is currently returned is raw text, which means `data[0]` accesses the first element (i.e. character) of the *string*, which is `{`. Obviously, you want to turn the returned data into a JSON object. To do this, [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) has a nifty property called `dataType`, which determines the way jQuery interprets the data returned from the AJAX call. Possible values are `'xml'`, `'json'`, `'script'`, and `'html'`. Simply set the `dataType` parameter to `'json'` in your code and you're set!

```
jQuery.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: StockSymbolUI,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ){
        jQuery( '.stock-table-outer' ).show();
        jQuery( '.stock-table-outer' ).html( data );
    }
} );
```